# How do virtual destructors work?

Tags: c++

I am using gcc. I am aware how the virtual destructors solve the problem when we destroy a derived class object pointed by a base class pointer. I want to know how do they work?

```
class A
{
      public:
      A(){cout<<"A constructor"<<endl;}
     ~A(){cout<<"A destructor"<<endl;}

};

class B:public A
{
      public:
      B(){cout<<"B constructor"<<endl;}
      ~B(){cout<<"B destructor"<<endl;}
};       

int main()
{
  A * a = new B();
  delete a;    
  getch();
  return 0;   
}
```

When I change A's destructor to a virtual function, the problem is solved. What is the inner working for this. Why do I make A's destructor virtual. I want to know what happens to the vtable of A and B?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key thing you need to know is that not using a virtual destructor in the above code is undefined behavior and that's not what you want. Virtual destructors are like any other virtual functions - when you call `delete` the program will decide what destructor to call right in runtime and that solves your problem.

Comment: @sharptooth: Why doesn't the same problem occur in the case of constructors?

Comment: @Jack When you constructed your object, you explicitly called `new B()`, so at that point the object is unambiguously a `B`, and so the `B` constructor was called. But when the object was deleted, what you deleted was an `A*`, so it is treated as if it were an `A` object, and so the `A` destructor is called unless it is virtual.

Comment: @Tyler McHenry: Thanks a lot that really cleared a lot of thing for me :)

Answer (score 6):

Virtual destructor is just a virtual function, so it adheres to the same rules.

When you call `delete a`, a destructor is implicitly called. If the destructor is not virtual, you get called `a->~A()`, because it's called as every other non-virtual function.

However if the destructor is virtual, you get `~B()` called, as expected: the destructor function is virtual, so what gets called is the destructor of derived class, not base class.

Edit:
Note that the destructor of the *base* class will be called implicitly after the destructor of the derived class finishes. This is a difference to the usual virtual functions.

Comment: but shouldn't virtual functions have the same name?

Comment: @Jack: usually yes; destructor is an exception.

Comment: @Jack: That would not be possible for destructors - they must have the same name as the class they belong to.

Comment: Luckily, the compiler treats all destructors as if they where the same function, "destroy()". So virtual overriding of the destructor works.

Comment: @Jack: this is so because of C++ conventions. In Delphi, for example, destructor can have name different from class name.

Comment: @Little Bobby Tables: Why doesn't the same problem occur in the case of constructors?

Comment: @Jack: there are no virtual constructors in C++ :-(

Comment: @Vlad: I know I might sound stupid but why wouldn't the same problem occur in case of constructors? I mean shouldn't compiler just call the base class constructor?

Comment: @Jack: there is no construction polymorphism in C++: with constructors, you always get an instance of the class according to the constructor you called. With destruction, it's more complicated: you can destroy an object by a pointer to the base class.

Comment: @Jack: because you tell the compiler *explicitly* which constructor to call so the compiler *knows* which one to call.

Comment: @Jack: please note that virtual constructor actually makes sense. See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.8 for more details.

Comment: @Vlad: Virtual destructors are no exception to the rule that virtual functions have the same name.  They do have the same name as the base class' destructor.  Destructors are unnamed.  `~MyObject` is just what you type to refer to the destructor -- it's not the destructor's name.

Comment: @Jack: When you call `B* b = new B` and `B` is derived from `A`, the `A` constructor is called within the initialization list for B.

Comment: @John: it's a question of convention. I prefer to _call_ `~A` a name for destructor of class `A`, because it can be used to refer to the destructor. After all, this is the essence of name -- you use it to refer to something.

Comment: @Vlad:  Understood, but it's not just a matter of convention.  According to the C++ standard, constructors and destructor are unnamed.

Comment: @John: Section 12.4 of standard (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf), paragraph 12 says: "In an explicit destructor call, the destructor **name** appears as a ~ followed by a type-name that names the destructor’s
class type." Doesn't this disprove your statement?

Comment: @Vlad: hmm...  I'm not sure actually.  Maybe.  But the std explicitly says that constructors do not have names, goes on to describe how constructors are declared & referred to, and then uses similar language describing how destructors are referred to & declared:  "A special declarator syntax using an optional function-specifier (7.1.2) followed by ~ followed by the destructor’s class
name followed by an empty parameter list is used to declare the destructor in a class definition."  So you might be right.

Comment: @Vlad:  I've posted a clarifying question, take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693199/do-destructors-have-names-according-to-the-standard

Comment: @John: thanks a lot, the question turned out to be by no means simple.