# C++ invoke explicit template constructor

Tags: c++, templates

Can you tell me how to invoke template constructor explicitly (in initializer list)?
for example:

```
struct T { 
    template<class> T();
};

struct U {
    U() : t<void>() {} //does not work
    T t;
};
```

thanks

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It's not possible. The Standard also has a note on this at `14.8.1/7`

> [Note: because the explicit template argument list follows the function template name, and because conversion member function templates and constructor member function templates are called without using a function name, there is no way to provide an explicit template argument list for these function templates. ]

**Explanation**: This says: Template arguments are passed in angle brackets after a function template name, such as `std::make_pair<int, bool>`. And constructors don't have a name of their own, but they abuse their class names in various contexts (so `U<int>()` means: Pass `<int>` to the class template `U`, and construct an object by calling the default constructor without arguments). Therefore, one cannot pass template arguments to constructors.

In your case, you are trying to pass template arguments in a member initializer. In that case, there's even more of a problem: It will attempt to parse and interpret `t<void>` as a base-class type and thinks you want to call the default constructor of a base class. This will fail, of course.

If you can live with it, you can work it around

```
struct T { 
    template<class U> T(identity<U>);
};

struct U {
    U() : t(identity<void>()) {}
    T t;
};
```

Given `identity` like it's defined in boost

```
template<typename T> struct identity { typedef T type; };
```

Within C++20 you can use `std::type_identity` as identity type.

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity

Comment: @litb: Do you know if there's any reason they simply don't let you explicitly call T::T<foo>()?

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  The same workaround can be used to call a templated constructor via `std::vector::emplace_back()` etc.

Comment: This answer could be improved if you explained what the Standard is talking about. I read it multiple times, and I'm still confused. It seems like you took our understanding it for granted, but not everyone is a Language Lawyer ;)

Comment: @KeithM you can specify what confuses you and then we may surely be able to clarify your understanding of the note. Maybe this is enough: If you use `T()`, then `T` is the name of the struct `T`, and not the name of the constructor (which doesn't have one). So if you say `T<...>()` then whatever arguments are passed, are not passed to the constructor, but are tried to be passed to the struct, which is not a template at all.

Comment: It's just kind of a word salad, there. `explicit template argument list`, `function template name`, `conversion member function templates`, `constructor member function templates`. I understood virtually none of that abstract terminology (sorry, couldn't resist the pun). After reading your new comment and the paragraph again, I might understand (although I still don't know the terminology). I think it's saying that `: t<void>()` doesn't work because template affixes always come after type names or function names, and `t` is neither. Is that right? (But why not change the std to allow it?)

Comment: (Ran out of chars, so double posting) By the way, I thought Constructors/Destructors had names, but the names matched the type names (plus a prefixed ~ for d'tor). Hence why you could do `T t(); t.T();` if you really wanted to (although that would call the c'tor twice). No?

Comment: @KeithM I have added an explanation for the note.

Comment: @KeithM as for the reason, I don't know, but could guess they didn't find a compelling use case. Maybe you could create a new question for this.

Comment: @Keith: [No](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.ctor#general-1.sentence-2) (the standard wording isn't quite as clear about destructors, but [we can probably agree the same is true for them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693199/4386278))