# how do you call this template constructor?

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ invoke explicit template constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786946/c-invoke-explicit-template-constructor)

Hi,

```
template <typename T>
class testing
{
public:

    template <typename R>
    testing()
    {
       // constructor A
    }

    template <typename R>
    testing(const R&)
    {
       // constructor B
    }
};
```

What is the syntax to invoke the constructor A?

I will need the type to be passed during the constructor call. Is there a way to call it? constructor B is a workaround as I only need to know the type not the whole object.

Thanks,

Stephen

Comment: sorry for the duplication, as I have no idea what to search for this one. Thanks for the reply below guys.

Comment: That's the issue with searching: when you don't know the term to qualify the problem, it's very hard to search for...

Answer (score 3):

you can create workaround:

```
template<class A>
testing(boost::mpl::identity<A>);

// and instantiate like this
testing(boost::mpl::identity<A>());
```

I asked very similar question before
[C++ invoke explicit template constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786946/c-invoke-explicit-template-constructor)

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The class template is based on the type `T`, so any template parameter you pass while instantiating the class will match `T` and not `R`.

**Edit:** You may also find this post useful: [Constructor templates and explicit instantiation](http://learningcppisfun.blogspot.com/2007/02/constructor-templates-and-explicit.html)

You should go ahead with the workaround (constructor B). Most modern compilers will optimize out the unused parameter, so it should make no difference.

Comment: Yes. the constructor A (constructor without argument) cannot be called. Although the compiler does not seem to give warning when it sees the class definition, there is just no way to call it.