# c++ call specific template constructor of template class

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

Is it possible to call a constructor with template arguments if the class is a template too?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

template <class A>
struct Class
{
  template <class B>
  Class(B arg) { std::cout << arg << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
  Class<int> c<float>(1.0f);
  Class<int>* ptr = new Class<int><float>(2.0f);
  return 0;
}
```

edit: so I guess the only way to call a specific template constructor is to call it with casted paramterers to the template type you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

template <class A>
struct Class
{
  template <class B>
  Class(B arg) { std::cout << arg << std::endl; }

  Class(double arg) { std::cout << "double" << std::endl; }
  Class(float arg) { std::cout << "float" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
  Class<int> c(1.0f);
  Class<int>* ptr = new Class<int>((double)2.0f);
  return 0;
}
```

// this outputs:
float
double

**edit2: but what happens to constructor template arguments that are not part of the constructor arguments itself ?**

```
template <class B, class C>
Class(B arg) { /* how do you specify ?? C */ }
```

Comment: Note that your constructor should be able to infer the type of the argument you pass to him without having to specify it explicitely.

Comment: Could you add some punctuation to the question? I'm not sure how to parse it!

Comment: A possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786946/c-invoke-explicit-template-constructor). Note that the outer class being a template is irrelevant.

Comment: I think edit2 deserved a question of his own.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358882/c-template-constructor-weirdness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> edit2: but what happens to constructor template arguments that are not part of the constructor arguments itself ?

Then you can pass-in an argument that has it encoded

```
template<typename T> struct encodeType { };

struct A {
  template<typename T, typename U>
  A(T t, encodeType<U>) { }
};

A a(1, encodeType<float>());
```

Answer (score 4):

In the example you gave you actually **don't need to** explicitly give the `template` argument to invoke constructor like:

```
Class<int> c<float>(1.0f);
```

Simply providing argument as `1.0f` is enough:

```
Class<int> c(1.0f);
```

Same thing is applicable for `new` example too. Having said that, I don't think constructor you can invoke explicitly using `template` argument (unlike normal function).

Answer (score 1):

```
Class<int> c(1.0f); //f in 1.0 makes it float type!
Class<int>* ptr = new Class<int>(2.0f);
```

This is enough. It will invoke the constructor which has template argument `float`. From the argument `1.0f`, the compiler will deduce the type argument of the constructor template. Since `1.0f` is `float`, so the type argument the compiler will deduce is `float`.

Likewise see these:

```
Class<int> c(1.0); //this will invoke Class<int><double>(double);
Class<int>* ptr = new Class<int>(2); //this will invoke Class<int><int>(int);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly state the template type that goes with the class itself (that's `A` in your example).  But you don't need to say what type `B` is.  The compiler knows from you passing `1.0f` that `B == float`.  There's nothing in the constructor call to help the compiler figure out what `A` is, so you have to tell it:

```
Class<int> c(1.0f);
Class<int>* ptr = new Class<int>(2.0f);
```