# Template constructor weirdness

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can the template parameters of a constructor be explicitly specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861839/can-the-template-parameters-of-a-constructor-be-explicitly-specified)

following up on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357394/c-call-specific-template-constructor-of-template-class), (I found this situation in edit 2)

Laid out simple in code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Printer
{
  Printer() { std::cout << "secret code" << std::endl; }
};

template <class A>
struct Class
{
  template <class B, class C>
  Class(B arg)
  {
      C c; /* the 'secret code' should come from here */
      std::cout << arg << std::endl;
  }

  Class(double arg) { std::cout << "double" << std::endl; }
  Class(float arg) { std::cout << "float" << std::endl; }

  /* this forbids the use of printer in the first parameter */
  Class(Printer printer) { throw std::exception(); /* here be dragons */ }
};

int main()
{
  Class<int> c(1.0f);
  Class<int>* ptr = new Class<int>((double)2.0f);
  return 0;
}

// Can anyone print 'secret code' while creating an object of type 'Class' ?
```

Detailed: For a template constructor, can you specify a template argument which is not part of the constructor's arguments when an object get's instantiated?

I think this deserves a question of its own.

Comment: The syntax for such a thing would have to look like `Class<A> objectA<B, C>(initB);`, which I don't think is allowed (I'll leave it to someone else to quote chapter and verse, I don't have the standard memorized). At the very least, if this were possible, you'd probably have to declare the template constructor `explicit` since there's no way to determine `C` when implicitly constructing a temporary. The *real* questions are: Why do you need to do such a thing, would a traits class solve your problem, and if not, why not?

Comment: currently it is just a programming curiosity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

There is no syntax with which you can provide explicit template parameters to a constructor template. You can only provide explicit template parameters for the class template as a whole.

The following text from `[temp.arg.explicit]` (2003 wording, 14.8.1/5) covers the scenario. Though the clause is non-normative, it serves to explain to us that, as an inherent restriction of the grammar, this is not possible:

> Note: because the explicit template
>   argument list follows the function
>   template name, and **because** conversion
>   member function templates and
>   **constructor member function templates
>   are called without using a function
>   name**, **there is no way to provide an
>   explicit template argument list for
>   these function templates**.

This, partially, comes out of the fact that you never actually invoke the constructor explicitly yourself. When you write, say, `A()` you are not calling the constructor like a function, even though it looks as if you are ("conversion member function templates and constructor member function templates are called without using a function name").

Comment: I tend to agree, but when this question was last debated, all that was clear is that the standard itself isn't very clear.

Comment: @James: I don't follow. `int` there is a class template parameter, no?

Comment: @Tomalak Yes.  I realized my mistake just as I was clicking on the send button, and have edited my response to delete the part which was wrong.

Comment: @James: I have edited my answer. This is clear by deduction from the grammar, and the standard contains a clear explanation of this deduction.

Comment: @James refers to the discussion he and me had about it. It's true that you cannot provide arguments when *calling* the constructor template (this is a bit imprecise - you *can* actually try to call a ctor directly and then provide template arguments, but directly calling it (i.e with fuction-call syntax) is ill-formed), however explicit arguments can be provided in other contexts (explicit instantiation, explicit specialization). But that isn't really useful on its own :) This assertion of me can be found in the discussion's comment list.

Comment: Insofar, I totally agree with your reasoning, "This, partially, comes out of the fact that you never actually invoke the constructor explicitly yourself.".

Comment: @litb: "you can actually try to call a ctor directly and then provide template arguments, but directly calling it is ill-formed" please explain this. It reads to me as "you can call a ctor directly, but you can't call a ctor directly."

Comment: @Tomalak "i can drive a car, but I'm not allowed to" ("shall not") vs "i cannot drive a car but i'm allowed to" ("cannot", "no able") vs "i cannot drive a car and i'm not allowed to." ("cannot" / "not able" too). Since by 3.4.3.1, `Class<int>::Class<float, double>` refers to a constructor function template specialization, you can use that in a call (you can call functions). But 3.4.3.1 also says "Such a constructor name shall be used only in the declarator-id of a constructor definition that appears outside of the class definition.". So you are, effectively, not allowed to do the call.

Comment: @litb: Ah, ok. So "you can actually try to call a ctor directly and then provide template arguments, but you shan't."

Comment: Yeah if the goal is to have a well-formed program, then I think one can say "you cannot" :) This is like private/public function calls. For sure you can call an inaccessible function, but you shall not. BTW I'm not notified by your follow-up comments if you use the "@litb" comment because my nick doesn't start with "litb". I don't know what other nice follow-up comments you made in the past that I missed out that way -.-

Answer (score 0):

I think he want to know how to instantiate this class with C as SomeType:

```
template<typename A>
class foo
{
    template<typename B, typename C>
    foo(B b)
    {
        C c;
    }
};
```

I don't know if this is possible.