# Nested template requires explicit construction?

Tags: c++

I have a nested template inside a parent template.  I'd like instances of the nested template to be convertible to other classes instantiated from the same template (but with different parameters.)  To do this, I create a constructor for the nested template that can take different template parameters:

```
template <class T>
struct Foo
{

    template <class U>
    struct Bar
    {
        Bar() { }

        template <class X, class Y>
        Bar(typename Foo<X>::template Bar<Y> b)
        {

        }
    };

};
```

This should enable the following expression to compile:

```
Foo<int>::Bar<int> b = Foo<char>::Bar<char>();
```

However, it ***doesn't*** actually compile.  It gives the compiler error:

```
error: conversion from ‘Foo<char>::Bar<char>’ to non-scalar type ‘Foo<int>::Bar<int>’ requested
  Foo<int>::Bar<int> b = Foo<char>::Bar<char>();
```

So, I'm confused.  Why doesn't this compile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Why does the second version compile?

Because the second one doesn't create a `Foo<int>::Bar<int>`. You've run into the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Had you attempted you *use* the `b` that appears to work, you'd have received further compiler errors showing that your `b` is in fact declared as a function.

Try this:

```
Foo<int>::Bar<int> b((Foo<char>::Bar<char>()));  // works fine? are you sure? :)
//                   ^                      ^
```

Your root problem is that the arguments will not be deduced<sup>†</sup>, and [you cannot provide them explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6359067/560648) because we do not use function-call syntax *per se* when a constructor is invoked.

---

#### <sup>†</sup> *Why* won't they be deduced?

To demonstrate, observe the following modified code where I replace the non-default constructor with a member function:

```
template <class T>
struct Foo
{

    template <class U>
    struct Bar
    {
        Bar();
        
        template <class X, class Y>
        void foo(typename Foo<X>::template Bar<Y> b)
        {}
    };
};

int main()
{
    //Foo<int>::Bar<int> b = Foo<char>::Bar<char>();
    Foo<int>::Bar<int> i;
    i.foo(Foo<char>::Bar<char>());
}
```

This gives us some more information to go on, wherein [the key error is](http://ideone.com/DU3Khy):

```
prog.cpp:11:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cpp:23:30: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘X’
  i.foo(Foo<char>::Bar<char>());
```

Changing the call, providing explicit arguments, to:

```
i.foo<char,char>(Foo<char>::Bar<char>());
```

yields a successful compilation; but this doesn't help us in our original code, as we cannot provide explicit arguments to a constructor invocation.

So, we're stuck with deduction, but unfortunately the nestedness breaks this for us through the following series of rules:

> `[C++11: 14.8.2.1/5]:` These alternatives are considered only if type deduction would otherwise fail. If they yield more than one possible deduced `A`, the type deduction fails. *[ Note:* **If a *template-parameter*** is not used in any of the function parameters of a function template, or **is used only in a non-deduced context, its corresponding *template-argument* cannot be deduced from a function call and the *template-argument* must be explicitly specified.** *—end note ]*
>
> `[C++11: 14.8.2.5/5]:` The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> - *[..]*
> - The [*nested-name-specifier*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4103791/560648) of a type that was specified using a *qualified-id*.
> - *[..]*

In short, we cannot expect the `X` in `Foo<X>::Bar<Y>` to be deduced, and that's where everything breaks down. So, basically, you can't do this. Sorry.

Comment: But what's the actual reason the code doesn't work? It really looks like it should...

Comment: Oh, right, it's just the usual non-deducible context, isn't it? It's the `X` you can't deduce, since indeed *any* `X` would do.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I still don't _quite_ get it; I think any `X` _won't_ do since `Foo<char>::Bar<char>` and, say, `Foo<bool>::Bar<char>` are different types!

Comment: @KerrekSB: Okay, maybe I've got the wording now; it's down to the nestedness, though as above I'm not sure _why_. I would still prefer 100% normative text, too. :(

Comment: That quote sounds right. `Foo<X>` is the nested-name-specifier, so `X` cannot be deduced.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Maybe it's an infeasible-complexity-of-implementation problem.

Comment: I think it's a simple sense-making problem. Imagine you have `template <typename T> void foo(typename Bar<T>::type);` and you call `foo(5)`. There's no sensible way to select a `T` for which `Bar<T>::type` is `int`. The preimage relationship is not a functional one.

Comment: You wrote that you modified the original copy constructor. Please note that the original constructor is *not* a *copy* constructor. A templated constructor is *never* a copy constructor. (If you want to write a constructor taking any instance of the template class, write a templated constructor plus a copy constructor (taking the exact same type)).

Comment: @leemes: Ah, you're right, of course. I keep making that mistake in nomenclature, though I don't believe it affects the answer beyond trivialities.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yeah, I suppose not, in the general case. In this specific case, it _could_ theoretically be deduced since `Foo<X>::Bar<Y>` (for some known `X` and `Y`) is a concrete class with no ambiguities in specialisation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I don't think I believe that: `Foo<X1>::Bar<Y>` is the same type as `Foo<X2>::Bar<Y>`, isn't it?

Comment: @KerrekSB: I don't think so? `[C++11: 9.7/1]:` *A class can be declared within another class. A class declared within another is called a nested class. **The name of a nested class is local to its enclosing class. The nested class is in the scope of its enclosing class.*** And recall that `Foo<X1>` and `Foo<X2>` are distinct classes.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612378/nested-template-requires-explicit-construction/19612457?noredirect=1#comment29114325_19612457 :P