# How to select constructor template?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ invoke explicit template constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786946/c-invoke-explicit-template-constructor)

First imagine I have a class Data with a templated member function :-

```
class Data
{
public:
    template <class Loader> void load(const std::string& filename);
};
```

I can use this like this -

```
Data data;
data.load<SomeLoader>(filename);
```

and all works fine. I can select at compiler time via the template parameter which class I want my Data object to use to load some data.

However I can't work out how to do this with constructors...

```
class Data
{
public:
    template <class Loader> Data(const std::string& filename);
};
```

That seems to compile perfectly well, but I can't seem to work out how to actually call the function.

```
Data<SomeLoader> data;
```

That doesn't work because that would invoke a class template, not a templated constructor.

Is there some syntax I'm missing here?
( If I add a constructor paramater of SomeLoader type, then the compiler correctly infers the class to use, but that's not what I need to do here)

Comment: Ah, I searched for this and failed to find anything. Thanks for adding the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not missing any syntax. It is impossible to explicitly use a specialisation of a constructor template.

The standard has a note about this at `[temp.arg.explicit]/7`:

> Because the explicit template argument list follows the function template name, and because con- version member function templates and constructor member function templates are called without using a function name, there is no way to provide an explicit template argument list for these function templates.

Comment: Can you provide some documentation on this?

Comment: @Luchian Hardly. There won’t be a paragraph in the standard saying “there is no syntax for calling a constructor with explicit template instantiation” (by the way, you *can* do this, using placement new. But let’s not go there …) **EDIT** Oh. Apparently the standard *does* provide explicit wording on this one. How thoughtful. See duplicate.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Ahh, there it is, I knew I'd seen that somewhere.

Comment: Hmm, well thank you. But that's irritating!

Comment: @JohnB: You can always pass a tag parameter to the constructor, and then use argument deduction on that.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible to do, since the compiler is not able to deduce the type, and you can not pass it to the constructor.

Few possible solutions :
1. make the Data class a template
2. pass some parameter to the constructor. This might be a better solution to use a dependency injection and pass the loader to the constructor.