# Instantiate an object of template class type in C++

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I am having troubles instantiating an object of a template class type in C++.

Here is the code:

Array.h:

```
//Developed by Trofimov Yaroslav on 30.03.2018

#ifndef _ARRAY_H_TROFIMOV_
#define _ARRAY_H_TROFIMOV_

template<size_t n, typename T>
class Array
{
        static unsigned __freeId, __quantity;
        unsigned _id;

        T* _array;
public:
        template<size_t n, typename T>
        Array(void);
        ~Array(void);
        T& operator[](const size_t);
};
#include "Array.cpp"

#endif
```

Array.cpp:

```
//Developed by Trofimov Yaroslav on 30.03.2018
#include "Array.h"

template<size_t n, typename T>
Array::Array(void) 
    : _id(++__freeId), _array(new T[]) {

}

template<size_t n, typename T>
Array::~Array(void) {

}

template<size_t n, typename T>
T& Array::operator[](const size_t i) {

}
```

Main.cpp:

```
//Developed by Trofimov Yaroslav on 30.03.2018
#include <iostream>
#include "Array.h"

int main(void) {
    Array<7, int> a;
    return 0;
}
```

Now when I hover over `a` in `Main.cpp` I see the following:

> Error: no default constructor exists for class "Array<7U, int>"

But as you can see, the default template constructor does exist. So, what am I missing here?

Comment: `template<size_t n, typename T> Array(void);` --> `Array();` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: @liliscent, thanks. I read the post before, but still I can not tackle my issue here.

Comment: @ggghahaha like liliscent said, you need to remove the extra `template` from the constructor, it doesn't belong there. Also, in your cpp file, you need to replace all of the `Array::` with `Array<n, T>::`

Comment: [C++ invoke explicit template constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2786946/3309790)

Comment: @RemyLebeau, after replacing the first `Array::` and removing `template` I got the error as a wrong syntaxis. Hence, I see no use in you advice.

Comment: @ggghahaha what I said earlier does apply. But there are other errors in the code that also have to be fixed, too. [Then it works fine](https://ideone.com/6Tdcgh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your code.

In your header file, you need to remove the extra `template` from the constructor, it doesn't belong there.

In your cpp file, you need to replace all of the `Array::` with `Array<n, T>::`.  Your constructor needs to pass `n` to `new[]`. Your destructor needs to `delete[]` the array. And `operator[]` needs to return something.

Your class has `static` members, so you need to instantiate instances of them as well.

Try this:

Array.h

```
#ifndef _ARRAY_H_TROFIMOV_
#define _ARRAY_H_TROFIMOV_ 

template<size_t n, typename T>
class Array
{
        static unsigned __freeId, __quantity;
        unsigned _id;

        T* _array;
public:
        Array(void);
        ~Array(void);
        T& operator[](const size_t);
};

#include "Array.cpp"

#endif
```

Array.cpp

```
#include "Array.h" 

template<size_t n, typename T>
Array<n, T>::Array(void) 
    : _id(++__freeId), _array(new T[n]) {
}

template<size_t n, typename T>
Array<n, T>::~Array(void) {
    delete[] _array;
}

template<size_t n, typename T>
T& Array<n, T>::operator[](const size_t i) {
    return _array[i];
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Array.h"

template<> unsigned Array<7, int>::__freeId = 0;
template<> unsigned Array<7, int>::__quantity = 0;

int main() {
    Array<7, int> a;
    return 0;
}
```

[Live deno](https://ideone.com/6Tdcgh)

Comment: As far as I understood it is impossible to use `.cpp` for a template implementation and at the same time not to create template specialization beforehand of its usage. Am I right?

Comment: @ggghahaha You can separate template declarations from definitions, as long as they are done in the same translation unit, which this code does by having the `.h` file `#include` the `.cpp` file. If you tried to compile the `.cpp` as its own unit, then it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use template when declaring methods or constructors inside your class. The constructor you've declared is a templated method inside a templated class rather than a default constructor.

I'd never rely on errors from intellisense, sometimes it's plain wrong, running the compiler will generally produce more accurate more detailed error messages.

Comment: Just delete the template statement from your constructor declaration, then run the compiler which will tell you your next error

Comment: So, you basically do not help me to solve the problem, but change it to another one. What for are you doing that? I can always delete all my code and write some gibberish to get another - different from my error. And you are just proposing me to do that. Thank you, but I do not need such a help.