# Why is narrowing conversion not preventing this map.insert() of an incorrect type from failing?

Tags: c++, c++11

### Background

When inserting a `std::pair<uint64_t, uint64_t>` to a C++ `std::map<uint64_t, int>`, neither the compiler nor the program complains, even if the passed values are not possible for the data type `uint64_t`.

In other words, the **narrowing conversion** of `std::pair<uint64_t, uint64_t>(2, -2)` isn't working and is defaulting to the map's type `std::map<uint64_t, int>`

### Code

When I compile and execute the following code with `g++ -Wall -Wconversion -Wextra -pedantic test/test_wrong_insert.cpp && ./a.out`:

```cpp
#include<map>
#include<iostream>

void print_map(std::map<uint64_t, int> & m){
  std::cout << "The map is now: {";
  for (const auto & n: m){
    std::cout << '(' << n.first << ',' << n.second << ") ";
  }
  std::cout << "}\n";
}

int main(){
  std::map<uint64_t, int> m;

  auto ret = m.insert(std::pair<uint64_t, uint64_t>(2,-2));
  std::cout << "Tried to insert std::pair<uint64_t, uint64_t>(2,-2). ";
  std::cout << "Return: " << ret.second << '\n';
  print_map(m);
}
```

### Result

... this is the output:

```
Tried to insert std::pair<uint64_t, uint64_t>(2,-2). Return: 1
The map is now: {(2,-2) }
```

### Question

Why does `std::pair<uint64_t,uint64_t> x{-1,-2}` not produce an error, and how do I make it cause an error?

Comment: Which compiler/version(s) have you tried?

Comment: I'm using g++ 7.8.0 for this project. Trying clang now...

Comment: I think viable way would be to create/override `std::pair` with object with constructor that accepts `int` as override and rejects negative ones. Probably it is even possible to raise compilation error on negative constants, but not sure if benefit would worse the effort.

Comment: i am not sure if I understand the question. Is it basically why `std::pair<uint64_t,uint64_t> x{-1,-2};` does not produce an error and how to make it cause an error?

Comment: @user463035818, correct - that is what I am trying to ask.

Comment: I think the problem here is that the ability to use negative values to initialize unsigned integral types is an intentional feature of the language (used in the standard library I believe).  For example, `size_t max_value = -1`.  And as for conversions, I don't see any narrowing conversions - your values got placed into the map correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does `std::pair<uint64_t,uint64_t> x{-1,-2}` not produce an error?

This is caused by a constructor template that participates in overload resolution when both arguments can be used to construct objects of `uint64_t` (or whatever type you instantiated `std::pair` with). It is overload (3) in the list of `std::pair` [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair), and its template argument deduction leads to a conversion that is taken as *intentional* (as in `auto n = uint64_t{-42};` or `static_cast<uint64_t>(-42);`) - hence no warning. There's not much you can do about it, as the template parameters of a constructor template can't be given explicitly, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786946/c-invoke-explicit-template-constructor).

> [...] how to make it cause an error?

Use `std::make_pair` and don't rely on template argument deduction:

```
auto p = std::make_pair<uint64_t, uint64_t>(-42, -42);
//         Be explicit: ^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^
```

When you compile the above snippet with `-Wsign-conversion` (important: `-Wconversion` won't cath it!), it will give you a warning (obviously, add `-Werror`  to treat it as an error).

The issue with `std::map::insert` is the same, see overload (2) [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert). This turns any usable given argument into a `value_type` object, and treats it as any conversion would be the caller's intention. Interestingly, the equivalent member function on a `std::set` is more restricted. So this is caught:

```
std::set<uint64_t> s;

s.insert(-42); // complains with -Wsign-conversion
```

Comment: does `make_pair` really warn about it? Maybe i missed it then I could delete my answer

Comment: ah i missed `-Wsign-conversion`