# Virtual destructors rules

Tags: c++, memory

I'm having a bit of confusion on when and why to use virtual destructors.

```
class Q { 
private: 
    int i; 
    int *pi; 
    int *p; 
public: 
    Q(int k); 
    print(); 
    ~Q() {delete pi; delete p;} 
}; 
class DQ : public Q 
{
private: 
    int *pd; 
public: 
    DQ(); 
    ~DQ(); 
};
```

I understand that if in the main I allocate a

```
Q *p = new DQ();
```

and do delete p, then only the destructor of Q is called.

But what happens in each one of those cases:

1. Only ~Q() is virtual while ~DQ() is not?
2. Only ~DQ() is virtual while ~Q() is not?
3. ~Q() is virtual and ~DQ() is virtual?

Comment: `virtual ~Q()` implies all derived destructors are likewise virtual. so (1) is moot. I cannot comment on (2) without reviewing the standard. For (3) see (1). In general, it is UB to fire base-class destruction through a non-polymorphic pointer (or so it was last time I checked pre-C++11 and I cannot imagine this has changed).

Comment: Some hints here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690473/how-do-virtual-destructors-work?rq=1

Comment: If you delete an object of a derived type through a pointer to the base the behavior is undefined. It is **not** required that the destructor of `Q` is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.) if `~Q()` is virtual, `~DQ()` is virtual whether you write `virtual` or not, so both destructors will be called

2.) Calling `delete p;` is undefined behavior (will likely only call `Q`'s destructor, but could crash or do any number of things, as it's undefined). Virtual-ness is propagated down, not up.

3.) same case as #1 except you explicitly wrote `virtual` (which is good practice, by the way). Both destructors will be called

Answer (score 2):

> I'm having a bit of confusion on when and why to use virtual destructors.

You need a virtual destructor in a base class in order to delete objects polymorphically; that is, to delete objects of derived types via a pointer to the base type.

> I understand that if in the main I allocate a `Q *p = new DQ();` and do delete p, then only the destructor of Q is called.

No, you get undefined behaviour. It might call Q's destructor, or it might send an insulting email to your boss - the first is more likely, but in principle anything could happen.

> Only ~Q() is virtual while ~DQ() is not?

That's impossible. If a function is virtual in a class, then it is also virtual in any derived class.

> Only ~DQ() is virtual while ~Q() is not?

Then you aren't allowed to delete an object of type `DQ` via a pointer to `Q`; you'll get undefined behaviour if you try. But, if you derive another class from `DQ`, then you can delete them via a pointer to `DQ` (but *not* `Q`) thanks to its virtual destructor.

> ~Q() is virtual and ~DQ() is virtual?

Then all is well, and you can safely delete objects via base-class pointers.

Comment: Any reason for the downvotes? I'm fairly sure I've answered the question correctly, but please let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: It's a mystery to me too. This answer looks correct and complete.

Answer (score 1):

1.Both ~DQ() and ~Q() are called in the order of ~DQ(), ~Q(). 
2. Only ~Q() is called.
3.Both ~DQ() and ~Q() are called.

Comment: for 2, since the base destructor is not virtual, this will invoke only the derived destructor

Comment: Again: the behavior is undefined. That means that there is **no requirement**. If you want to report on what you've seen a particular compiler do, by all means do so, but **label** it as implementation-specific.