# Unexplainable behaviour of destructor

Tags: c++, destructor

In this question: [How do virtual destructors work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690473/how-do-virtual-destructors-work)

The top answer has the following note:

```
Note that the destructor of the base class will be called implicitly after the destructor of the derived class finishes. This is a difference to the usual virtual functions.
```

I put together a quick example program to test this,

```
class A {
public:
  virtual ~A() {
    std::cout << "A DESTRUCTOR" << std::endl;
  }
};
class B {
public:
  virtual ~B() {
    std::cout << "B DESTRUCTOR" << std::endl;
  }
};
class C {
public:
  virtual ~C() {
    std::cout << "C DESTRUCTOR" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  A * aPtr = (A *)new C();
  C * cPtr = new C();

  delete aPtr;
  delete cPtr;
  return 0;
}
```

The output I got was

```
C DESTRUCTOR
C DESTRUCTOR
```

Which does not seem to agree with the note.

My question is, how do you safely implement destructors in class hierarchies that need multiple destructors run?

Suppose, for example, that both class A and class C allocated a property on the heap and needed to clean them up.  How would I safely write a hierarchy like this?  NOTE: I'm not currently attempting to write a hierarchy like this, please don't respond with "don't, it's bad design".  Also, I understand smart pointer would resolve the problem, this is more about making sure I understand the underlying mechanisms.

Does it require the C class to clean up the A class property properly?  What happens if that property is private instead of protected or public?  Am I missing something, or misinterpreting what I'm seeing perhaps?

compiler being used to run these tests

```
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4
```

Comment: You forgot to make your classes derive from each other!

Comment: and where's the inheritance?

Comment: Most often, the program does what you type, not what you want! C is not derived from A and as such, your cast is of kind ``daring_hero_cast<A*>(pc)``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have noted, you want (need, really) to use inheritance here.

What they haven't noted is that the compiler only allowed you to do this at all because you used a cast in a place you *really* shouldn't have. If you need to use a cast, you *really* should sit back, think twice about *why* that cast is necessary, and be certain that what it's doing is really something you wanted to do.

Without the cast, the compiler would prevent your broken code from compiling. With the inheritance corrected, it's fine without the cast:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
  virtual ~A() {
    std::cout << "A DESTRUCTOR" << std::endl;
  }
};
class B : public A {
public:
  virtual ~B() {
    std::cout << "B DESTRUCTOR" << std::endl;
  }
};
class C : public B {
public:
  virtual ~C() {
    std::cout << "C DESTRUCTOR" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  A * aPtr = new C();

  delete aPtr;
}
```

Result:

```
C DESTRUCTOR
B DESTRUCTOR
A DESTRUCTOR
```

Comment: I meant to, not sure how I missed that didn't get done.  Doing too many things at once I suppose.  I'll mark as accepted as soon as I can.

Comment: Casts can be dangerous, the derived_ptr-to>base_ptr cast is allowed in the C++ language without any explicit cast due to the inheritance that relates them but other conversions require explicit action (as in your case)

Answer (score 4):

1. You forgot the inheritance between classes
2. This will trigger [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as soon as you execute the `delete` line

   ```
   A * aPtr = (A *)new C();
   ```

I believe [this](http://ideone.com/rujGYh) is what you were searching for

```
class A {
public:
  virtual ~A() {
    std::cout << "A DESTRUCTOR" << std::endl;
  }
};
class B : public A{
public:
  virtual ~B() {
    std::cout << "B DESTRUCTOR" << std::endl;
  }
};
class C : public B{
public:
  virtual ~C() {
    std::cout << "C DESTRUCTOR" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  A * aPtr = new C(); // The cast here is not needed
  C * cPtr = new C();

  delete aPtr;
  delete cPtr;
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
C DESTRUCTOR
B DESTRUCTOR
A DESTRUCTOR
C DESTRUCTOR
B DESTRUCTOR
A DESTRUCTOR
```

Comment: Technically, the cast is fine (it's a `reinterpret_cast`), the delete isn't.

Comment: That's why I wrote "it will trigger", as soon as the delete line is executed. It might be unclear though, I'll edit this in, thanks

Answer (score 0):

change to:

```
class A {
public:
  virtual ~A() {
    std::cout << "A DESTRUCTOR" << std::endl;
  }
};
class B : public A{
public:
  virtual ~B() {
    std::cout << "B DESTRUCTOR" << std::endl;
  }
};
class C : public B{
public:
  virtual ~C() {
    std::cout << "C DESTRUCTOR" << std::endl;
  }
```

};

Comment: Whilst this fixes the problem, it doesn't explain _why_. What makes you assume `C` should inherit from `B` instead of directly from `A`?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior your'e referring to here is the behavior of virtual destructors in *derived classes*, meaning classes with inheritance of other classes.

also remember to use g++ for c++ compilation.

Comment: you're right, I just popped over to the console and typed it in for completeness without thinking too hard about it :)